# Superfish dropdown menu renders too much white space in Chrome upon refresh

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, superfish

Im hoping someone has run into this problem before or can at least tell me why Chrome is doing this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW1SB.png

In the first image, the menu renders properly. Visiting the site for the first time will display the white space correctly. However, upon refresh or visiting another section of the website the white space enlarges to show what is the second image.

If I manually change the width of the menu item down to (80%) the white space still renders too large. Manually changing the .module or .css for the default.css superfish dropdown theme does not change this either. Chrome constantly overrides the change. This is not an issue in IE/Firefox/Opera/Safari and appears only in Chrome.

The website is located at: axiombeta.scdmarketing.com (sorry, apparently can't have two hyperlinks yet...)